# MaxScale after Failover the master-slave-configuration on previous slave server is resetted

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication, maxscale

After MaxScale Failover my configuration for the master/slave replikation on my slave server was resetted. Do I have to config it again?

I have configured a Master/Slave Replikation and Maxscale Read/write splitting. I've shutted down my master server so automatically my slave server was the new master server. After I restarted the old master server, my master slave configuration on the previous slave server (who became master after the failover) was resetted. Do I have to configure it again after a Failover ?

Comment: This is a question for the DBAs on the dba sister site of SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When a slave is promoted, its slave connections are removed. If the old master has recovered, you can use the "switchover"-feature in MaxScale to promote it to master.